# How to use js/jsx files in a typescript+webpack project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to import and use a regular `.jsx` file, located inside my `typescript` project built with `webpack`. I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App/Test.jsx 72:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (72:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|   return (
>     <span>
|       Search:{' '}
|       <input
```

The error message implies that I don't have a loader specified to handle `jsx` files. Fair enough, but which loader should I use? I tried both `ts-loader` to load the `jsx` files (which broke my project) and `awesome-typescript-loader` which didn't work either. I feel as though I've done the other things that are recommended:

- set "allowJs" to true in my `tsconfig.json`
- add `.jsx` files to the resolve part of my webpack config.
- define a rule (under module.rules) for `/\.jsx?$/` files in my webpack config.

This is the relevant part of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false, // disable the behaviour
        },
      }
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js",".jsx"],
    symlinks: true
  },
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "strict" : true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    /* Manual */
    "jsx" : "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re calling this a js file when it contains jsx?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I updated the question accordingly. The same error happens when I change it to a `jsx` file (as it should've been originally).

Comment: @SeanW Did all that but got this error: https://ibb.co/Jz2hjpd. In addition to that, I got another error saying `Cannot find module X. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?`). Also, my typescript project runs just fine without specifying `include` in the `tsconfig.json`, perhaps since I'm careful to define an `entry` in my webpack config.

Comment: @SeanW Yes I mean, I have a well-running typescript+webpack project already. I simply cannot add 1 *.jsx* file into it

Comment: @SeanW I don't believe so? They don't have a rule defined (under module -> rules) for loading `jsx` files. Only for `ts`/`tsx` files.

Comment: That's not the problem.  es5 modules don't have a few things in it that I would think would be required.  Look at the Ts config under "Let's set up a configuration to support JSX and compile TypeScript down to ES5"

Comment: @SeanW I used their tsconfig but get the same error; i.e. that I don't have a loader specified for `jsx` files. What resolved my problem was to use `babel-loader` for the js/jsx files and `ts-loader` for the ts/tsx files.

Answer (score 5):

you can add this for support `.tsx,.jsx` together `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.(tsx|jsx|ts|js)?$/,
    use: "babel-loader",
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  }
```

and add this to `.babelrc`:

```
{
"presets": [
  "@babel/typescript", 
  "@babel/preset-env",
  ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}]
 ]
}
```

finally change `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
  "start": "serve dist"
}
```

Comment: Can I do it without babel, just with tsc?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not possible and I had investigated this issue last year and it was possible with babel.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to put this into my `webpack.config.js`:

```
      {
        test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        },
```

Then I needed to run:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-react
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```